# Why does shift-tabbing through input fields not work with dijit.FieldSet on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dojo, fieldset

Given a set of input text fields grouped within several `dijit.FieldSet`s I am able to tab through the inputs both forwards and backwards using Firefox and IE8, but on Chrome, reverse tab navigation (shift-tabbing) stops at the first input within any given fieldset and does not continue to the next.

I noticed also that on Firefox and IE, the little arrow expander at the top-left of each fieldset is tab-navigable, but not with Chrome. May have something to do with it?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blah238/GCswY/) demonstrating the issue. Does anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

I am using Dojo 1.9.1.

Comment: Opened a ticket on the Dojo bug tracker: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17428

Answer (score 1):

Maybe chrome reverse tab is more sensitive to tabindex? if tabindex left blank they all default to 0.  Once i added a tabindex, it worked fine on chrome both ways.
Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/GCswY/2/

```
<fieldset data-dojo-type="dijit/Fieldset">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" tabindex="1"/>
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" tabindex="2"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset data-dojo-type="dijit/Fieldset">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" tabindex="3"/>
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" tabindex="4"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset data-dojo-type="dijit/Fieldset">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" tabindex="5"/>
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" tabindex="6"/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: That does indeed fix the problem in the example. I am wary of using it in my real application though, not sure if it might break other things, plus that would be very tedious to have to write out manually. So I am still curious about the root cause. Anyways, thanks!